# NEST mapping of Dictionary<string,dynamic> getting empty arrays

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When trying to deserialize a field containing a Json from my database to index in elasticsearch all the nested fields are getting empty array as a value.

```
{
    "_index": "dev",
    "_type": "user",
    "_id": "072512c2-fc23-471a-9e07-65c3a041f06b",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "providerInfos": """{"Global":{"Email":"email@hotmail.com","FirstName":"Name","LastName":"Last Name","PostalCode":"XXXXXX","Address":"99 Street","Town":"City","Gender":"M","PhoneNumber":null,"CreatedDate":"2018-04-14T14:34:42.4850547Z","LastLoginDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}}""",
      "providers": {
        "Global": {
          "Email": [],
          "FirstName": [],
          "LastName": [],
          "PostalCode": [],
          "Address": [],
          "Town": [],
          "Gender": [],
          "PhoneNumber": [],
          "CreatedDate": [],
          "LastLoginDate": []
        },
```

My code to deserialize is as follow:

```
public class User : IdentityUser

  public string JsonInfo { get; protected set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Infos
    {
        get => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(JsonInfo ?? "") ??
               new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    }
}
```

In the JsonInfo field on my database I have this, for exemple:

```
{"Global":{"Email":"email@hotmail.com","FirstName":"Name","LastName":"Last Name","PostalCode":"XXXXXX","Address":"99 Street","Town":"City","Gender":"M","PhoneNumber":null,"CreatedDate":"2018-04-14T14:34:42.4850547Z","LastLoginDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}}
```

And to index it all:

```
var users = await uow.GetRepository<FedecpIdentityUser, string>().GetAsync();
var indexAllAsync = users
    .Select(u => _elasticSearch.Client.IndexAsync(u, p => p.Id(u.Id.ToString()))).ToList();
```

I noted that this happens after I updated Nest from 5.4 to 6.02, could that be it? I haven't found anything about this in the changelogs.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is related to the internalization of Json.NET in 6.x and the use of `dynamic` in your code.

`dynamic` will actually be deserialized to `JToken` types by Json.NET, which NEST will not know how to serialize, since the internalized Json.NET for all intents and purposes can be considered a different assembly that knows nothing about `Newtonsoft.Json` types.

To fix, you can reference [`Nest.JsonNetSerializer` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) and [hook up the `JsonNetSerializer` as the serializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) for NEST to use for your documents

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings =
    new ConnectionSettings(pool, sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default);
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with `dynamic`, and it was fixed by making this change.